# How to optimize the cleaning of Twitter texts?

Tags: regex, scala

How can I rewrite the text cleaning function and make it more efficient?

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer2

// A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
private val whiteSpaceRegex = "\\p{Space}"
// Any except letter (subtraction)
private val exceptLetterRegex = "[^\\p{L}]"

val normalize = (str: String) => Normalizer2.getNFKCCasefoldInstance.normalize(str)

val cleanse = (str: String) => normalize(str) // 1
  .toLowerCase // 2
  .split(whiteSpaceRegex) // 3
  .filterNot( // 4
    p => p.startsWith("@") || p.startsWith("/") || p.startsWith("http") || p.startsWith("www")
  ).mkString(" ") // 5
  .replaceAll("-", "") // 6
  .replaceAll(exceptLetterRegex, " ") // 7
  .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ") // 8
  .trim // 9
```

1. normalize letters in string
2. change string to lower case
3. split string to Array[String] by whitespaces
4. filter out Twitter-specific words: links, nicknames
5. make String again
6. glue words with a hyphen (like: ex-wife to exwife)
7. replace all except letters by space
8. replace multiple spaces with single
9. remove first and last space

Tests:

```
val strMultiLine =
  """RT @digger: Что-то пиддес52 :|
и так скучать( HERE_HTTP_T_DOT_CO_LINK что,я +100500 surf cвихнусь так D:"""

val res1 = "rt чтото пиддес и так скучать что я surf cвихнусь так d"

cleanse(strMultiLine) must equal(res1)

val strWithLineBreak =
  "Говорит: \"\"Кто то в углу сидит))) и погибает от голода!!! мы,хотя уже сидим из-за\"\" :DD …"

val res2 = "говорит кто то в углу сидит и погибает от голода мы хотя уже сидим изза dd"

cleanse(strWithLineBreak) must equal(res2)
```

- HERE_HTTP_T_DOT_CO_LINK — Stackoverflow asked me to remove the link from the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is not much room for a lot of enhancements. I can recommend to shrunk the first part where you remove links or mentions and the non-letter removal into a single regex, but you need to remove hyphens beforehand then:

```
val cleanse2 = (str: String) => normalize(str)                  // Normalize
      .replace("-","")                                          // Remove -
      .replaceAll("""(?<!\S)(?:[@/]|http|www)\S*|\P{L}""", " ") // Remove entities
      .replaceAll("""\s{2,}""", " ")                            // Shrink whitespaces
      .trim                                                     // Trim the result
      .toLowerCase                                              // To lower case
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pRMxGQ/1).

The `(?<!\S)(?:[@/]|http|www)\S*|\P{L}` pattern matches

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string position must precede the current position immediately
- `(?:[@/]|http|www)\S*` - `@`, `/`, `http` or `www` and then any 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `\P{L}` - any non-letter char.